# How do you install packages/libraries without Cabal or Cabal-Install?

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, cabal, cabal-install

I'm trying to set up Haskell from scratch, on Ubuntu 11.04, without using the outdated Debian repository or Haskell-Platform.

I've installed `GHC-7.0.4` from source with no problem, and now need to install Cabal (which appears to already be included in GHC in /usr/local/lib/ghc-7.0.4/Cabal-1.10.2.0) and `Cabal Install`.

The latter specifies several dependencies (`parsec` and `network`), each of which has several dependencies of their own (`mtl`, `text`, etc).

What's the command to install these packages, that I downloaded from hackage in tar.gz form?

Unpack, then runhaskell doesn't work.

I see Setup.lhs, but it's not clear what that's for or how to use it.

Most of the Haskell documentation I've found assumes you've installed from a repo or Haskell-Package and doesn't really explain this well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`cabal-install` has a shell script that does this. If you [download it from hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cabal-install/0.10.2/cabal-install-0.10.2.tar.gz) and install it, you can start `bootstrap.sh` to install `cabal-install`. You can then use it to install other packages.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that but it seemed from RWH that you need parsec and network installed first (http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/installing-ghc-and-haskell-libraries.html), and from the docs HTTP installed first before you can run bootstrap.sh.  I see now bootstrap.sh does all that for you.  That's what I get for doing this at 3am.

Answer (score 6):

There are two different packages: `Cabal` and `cabal-install`. Cabal is a library, and cabal-install is an executable named `cabal`.

To install a package, `cabal-install` is an optional convenience wrapper around Cabal, but Cabal is required.

According to http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Libraries , Cabal is a 'zero-boot' package, so when you build GHC, Cabal and its dependencies are built for you automatically.

You can use `ghc-pkg` executable to check which packages are already installed:

```
# ghc-pkg list
```

Check if Cabal is in the list after you build GHC. If yes, you can install more packages without cabal-install using this documentation:

http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal/How_to_install_a_Cabal_package

I suggest you to install `cabal-install` first, and then install everything else using `cabal-install` executable. A usual commandine for global installation is this:

```
# runhaskell Setup configure
# runhaskell Setup build
# sudo runhaskell Setup install
```

Unpack a package tarball and run the commands in the folder with `Setup.hs` or `Setup.lhs` files. Note that a per-user non-root installation is also supported - Use `runhaskell Setup configure --user`

When you install cabal executable and its dependencies this way, use `cabal install {package-name}` to install more packages.

Note that Haskell Platform exists mostly because of the pain of installing `cabal-install` by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I see i was using runhaskell Setup incorrectly.  Not firing on all cylinders at 3am. Much appreciated!